# Have this problem with calling stored procedure unknown object type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a query that needs to call a stored procedure. But it always throws an error:

> Unknown object type 'TABLEIXICHistoricalData' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement.

This is query:

```
USE ETLCourse

DECLARE @LOOP TABLE 
              (
                  ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
                  TableName NVARCHAR(100)
              )

INSERT INTO @LOOP (TableName)
    SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_Stocks%'

DECLARE @b INT = 1, @m INT, @t NVARCHAR(100)

SELECT @m = MAX(ID) FROM @LOOP

WHILE @b <= @m
BEGIN
    SELECT @t = TableName 
    FROM @LOOP 
    WHERE ID = @b

    EXECUTE [dbo].[stp_BuildNormalizedTable] @t

    SET @b = @b + 1
END
```

and here is the procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_BuildNormalizedTable]
    @table NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cleanTable NVARCHAR(100),
            @s NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @cleanTable = REPLACE(@table, '_Stocks', 'HistoricalData')

    SET @s = 'CREATE TABLE' + @cleanTable + '(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Price DECIMAL(13, 4), PriceDate DATE)
              INSERT INTO' + @cleanTable + '(Price,PriceDate) SELECT [Adj Close],[Date] FROM'
              + @table + ' ORDER BY Date ASC'

    --PRINT @s
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @s
END
```

It should copy two specific column and create a new table by using `@Loop` table and procedure

Comment: I think the problem might be inside the Procedure......

Comment: The new table name suppose to be xxxHistoricalData and two column has been filled from original table

Comment: "`SET @s = 'CREATE TABLE' + @cleanTable + ...`" -- there's no space between "`TABLE`" and the table name, for which you should also use `quotename()`: `SET @s = 'CREATE TABLE ' + quotename(@cleanTable) + ...` Same problem here: "`... Insert into' + @cleanTable ...`" and here "`... FROM' + @table...`.

Comment: @stickybit thank you ,you are right!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need to add 'space' after 'create table' and 'insert into' and 'from'**

```
declare @s nvarchar(max)
declare @cleantable nvarchar(100)
declare @table nvarchar(100)
set @cleantable = 'aaa'
set @table = 'bbb'

SET @s = 'CREATE TABLE' + @cleanTable + '(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),Price Decimal(13,4),PriceDate DATE)
Insert into' + @cleanTable
+ '(Price,PriceDate) SELECT [Adj Close],[Date] FROM'
+ @table + ' ORDER BY Date ASC'

print @s
```

---

Output:

```
CREATE TABLEaaa(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),Price Decimal(13,4),PriceDate DATE)
Insert intoaaa(Price,PriceDate) SELECT [Adj Close],[Date] FROMbbb ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Use 'print' to check your query.